# What is wrong in my code make it doesn't work on js fiddle?

Tags: reactjs, jsfiddle

It is the first time to use jsfiddle, but i spent bad time trying to make my very simple and basic code to work on it, i am sure i am missing something like website config

**code**:

```
export default fumction App() {
  return (
        <div>
          hello world
        </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**jsfiddle snippet**:
https://jsfiddle.net/Dr_Coder/Lo8uzgq3/4/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q9caswgk/ updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it makes no sense to `export default` on jsfiddle. The code is not a module exporting to something else. Further it's "function" not "fumction"

```
function App() {
  return (
        <div>
          hello world
        </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: I think yes you are right, the problem was in export default, thank you